# Adding Cache Attached to add Custom Selector to the grid of the Claim Expenses page

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have the following problem:

I want to add a custom selector to the InventoryID field of the EP301000 page grid from Acumatica but when I add a cache Attached to it:

1. The InventoryID selector changes correctly to my custom selector.
2. But when you select an item from the lookup the field keep showing its 
   information blank as if an item is not selected.
3. If the field data is filled by typing it the same thing happens and the field blanks itself.

So the lookup is showing the correct information but the field doesn't fill when you select the desired record.

Using a regular Selector also blanks the field.

I tried without the any selector, and the same thing happens - in this case,  item shows its integer value instead of the CD given that there is no Selector.

This is my extended graph:

```
public class ExpenseClaimEntrySSGExt : PXGraphExtension<ExpenseClaimEntry>
{

    #region Cache Attached

    #region InventoryID
    //Cache attached use:
    //Add Custom Selector
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Expense Item")]
    [SSGCustomExpenseItem(typeof(EPExpenseClaimDetails.contractID))]
    protected virtual void EPExpenseClaimDetails_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache Sender)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region CustomSelectors

    [PXDBInt]
    public class SSGCustomExpenseItemAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
    {
        private Type _ContractID;

        public SSGCustomExpenseItemAttribute(Type contractID)
            : base(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID))                                                           
        {
            _ContractID = contractID;

            this.SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD);
            this.DescriptionField = typeof(InventoryItem.descr);
        }

        private string GetSelection()
        {
            var cache = _Graph.Caches[_BqlTable];
            return cache.GetValue(cache.Current, _ContractID.Name)?.ToString(); //Gets the field value by the field name without raising any events.
        }

        protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
        {
            string contractString = GetSelection();
            int contractID = -1;

            contractID = Convert.ToInt32(contractString);
            if (contractID != -1)
            {
                Contract contractRow = PXSelect<Contract,
                                          Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>>>
                                       .Select(this._Graph, contractID);

                CSAnswers cSAnswersRow = PXSelect<CSAnswers,
                                            Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>,
                                                And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.attributeID>>>>>
                                         .Select(this._Graph, contractRow.NoteID, "DIRINDIREC");

                if (cSAnswersRow != null && cSAnswersRow.Value.Equals("IND"))
                {
                    foreach (InventoryItem row in PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem,
                                                    InnerJoin<INPostClass,
                                                        On<InventoryItem.postClassID, Equal<INPostClass.postClassID>>>,
                                                    Where<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<INItemTypes.expenseItem>,
                                                        And<INPostClass.postClassID, Equal<Required<INPostClass.postClassID>>>>>.Select(this._Graph, "IND"))
                    {
                        yield return row;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (InventoryItem row in PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem,
                                                    InnerJoin<INPostClass,
                                                        On<InventoryItem.postClassID, Equal<INPostClass.postClassID>>>,
                                                    Where<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<INItemTypes.expenseItem>,
                                                        And<INPostClass.postClassID, NotEqual<Required<INPostClass.postClassID>>>>>.Select(this._Graph, "IND"))
                    {
                        yield return row;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (InventoryItem row in PXSelect<InventoryItem,
                                                    Where<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<INItemTypes.expenseItem>>>.Select(this._Graph))
                {
                    yield return row;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be the UI control type of the EPExpenseClaimDetails.InventoryID field.

In the grid RowTemplate ASPX element, InventoryID is declared as a SegmentMask control instead of a Selector control:

```
<px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" AllowEdit="True" Size="XM" />
```

You should replace the PXSegmentMask control in the grid RowTemplate with a PXSelector control.

Simply removing it will allow the value to stick but you should replace SegmentMask with Selector in order to assign CommitChanges/AllowEdit/Size properties.

This is the control to replace, RowTemplate element is labelled Levels in customization project editor:
[image]